# FluentValidation on number issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

I have a MaxNumberTeamMembers property in my view model as such:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the maximum number of team members.
/// </summary>
public int MaxNumberTeamMembers { get; set; }
```

I want to know if the following ruleset is possible:

- On the front end view, if the textbox is empty then I want a "MaxNumberTeamMembers is required" message to be displayed
- If the number entered is less than 1 then I want a message to display "MaxNumberTeamMembers should be greater or equal to 1".

What would the ruleset for the above look like?

I have the following but it does not work on the GreaterThan part if I enter 0:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MaxNumberTeamMembers)
     .NotEmpty()
     .WithMessage("Max. number of team members is required")
     .GreaterThan(0)
     .WithMessage("Max. number of team members must be greater than 0");
```

**UPDATE 2011-02-14:**

```
RuleFor(x => x.MinNumberCharactersCitation)
   .NotNull()
   .WithMessage("Min. number of characters for citation is required")
   .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1)
   .WithMessage("Min. number of characters for citation must be greater than or equal to 1")
   .LessThanOrEqualTo(x => x.MaxNumberCharactersCitation)
   .WithMessage("Min. number of characters must be less than or equal to max. number of characters");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>If you want to handle the *empty* case you need a nullable integer on your model because otherwise it is the default model binder that will automatically add a validation error when it tries to parse the empty string to a non-nullable integer:</strike>

```
public int? MaxNumberTeamMembers { get; set; }
```

and then you could have the following validation rules on this property:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MaxNumberTeamMembers)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage("Max. number of team members is required")
    .Must(x => x.Value > 0)
    .When(x => x.MaxNumberTeamMembers != null)
    .WithMessage("Max. number of team members must be greater than 0");
```

---

UPDATE:

The following works fine with the latest version of FluentValidation:

```
RuleFor(x => x.MaxNumberTeamMembers)
    .NotNull()
    .WithMessage("Max. number of team members is required")
    .GreaterThan(0)
    .WithMessage("Max. number of team members must be greater than 0");
```

Comment: I kept my property an int, and I replaced the NotEmpty with NotNull, it works fine, but is your way better?

Comment: How would I add a regular expression to this so that the user only types in a numeric value in the textbox?  Is this by any means possible?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, you are correct, with the latest version of FluentValidation you no longer need to make your property a nullable integer and both NotNull and NotEmpty should work. As far as the regular expression is concerned I am afraid that it applies only to properties of type string and it cannot be done with integer values.

Comment: Cool.  How would I add a regular expression to this to check that only numbers are allowed to be entered in the textbox?  Is this possible with FV, or do I need to use something like jQuery?  When I type in a letter into this textbox then it displays a default message, not sure where this comes from.  Ideally I would like to validate this value entered with a regular expression (if possible) and display my own message to the user.

Comment: You could use the `.Matches(@"\d+")` rule but you need to modify the type of your property to string.

Comment: Yes I thought so.  No I want to keep it int.  This validation framework feels limited to me in what it can do.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, that's not a limitation of the fluent validation framework. It's the ASP.NET MVC works. The default model binder runs before the validator and when it encounters a property of type int it tries to parse the value in the request and if it fails it adds a model error.

Comment: We had a similar problem where we were trying to constrain a field to a 4 digit Int but there is no direct way in FluentValidation that I know of. Since FluentVlidation is using jQuery Validation on the client side, we have "hijacked" the editor to add an additional attribute which jQuery Validation recognized to restrict input to Integers:
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyInteger, new { maxlength = 4, data_val_regex_pattern = "^-?\\d+$", data_val_regex = "MyInteger must be a non decimal number." })`

Answer (score 2):

it is work with FluentValidation version 3.2

```
RuleFor(x => x.MaxNumberTeamMembers)
    .NotNull()
    .WithMessage("Please Enter Value")
    .InclusiveBetween(1, 500)
    .WithMessage("Value must be number Beetween 1 , 500");
```